# integration in 2D over delta function with 2 variables

Tags: education, mathematical-physics, computational-mathematics

I am quite new here, and was wondering if anybody knows how this 2D integral is evaluated.

$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(k_1 x-k_2y)\,dx\,dy$

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!!!

Comment: HINT: just apply a different set of coordinates:
$u=k_1x-k_2y$ and $v=k_1x+k_2y$, i believe the integral is $\frac{1}{2k_1k_2}$

Comment: The integral diverges. The argument for the delta is a line and the integrand is $1\delta$ diverges along that line.